# vim in xterm not redrawing properly

Tags: terminal, linux

Since this problem exists only when using vim in an xterm (neither gvim nor vim in aterm demonstrate this on my computer) this is likely not a vim problem, but because it is sooooo annoying when using vim but likely not too obvious otherwise I thought I'd ask here in case anyone immediately knows the solution!  Or in case anyone immediately tells me where I *should* post it :)

Starting with this simple file:

[image: Simple file correctly drawn]

Hit 'x' a few times and I get this:

[image: file not correctly drawn]

The trailing exclamation point is not erased as the line shortens.  When I resize the xterm window I get a complete mess.  As mentioned above, doesn't happen in gvim or in vim running in an aterm window.

vim-8.2.0814-r100
xterm-367
ncurses-6.2_p20210123

This is only happening on my laptop, everything works fine on my desktop (or I'd have lost my mind already!)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: what is your `set lazyredraw?` ?

Comment: And what is the output of `:echo $TERM` and `:set term?` in vim?

Comment: What about `:set cp? cpoptions?`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: ":set lazyredraw?" returns "nolazyredraw"  ":echo $TERM" prints "xterm" (and leaves "$TERM-[New File]" not redrawn as one would expect) "set term?" returns "term-xterm",  ":set cp? cpoptions?" returns "nocompatible" and on a new line "cpoptions=aABceFs"